# Making a bot using Microsoft Bot Framework. I can't send and introductory message

Tags: emulation, bots

At the moment most of the code is taken from the introductory tutorial here: http://docs.botframework.com/builder/node/guides/core-concepts/#navtitle. I am using the Microsoft Bot Framework Emulator to run my bot.

After the bot is added to the emulator I have to type in "hi" to start the bot. Ideally what I want is to have a welcome message pop up that prompts the user to say hi. This is my code:

```
var restify = require('restify');
var builder = require('botbuilder');

//create a bot
var bot = new builder.BotConnectorBot({appId: "YourAppID", appSecret: "YourAppSecret", groupWelcomeMessage: "Welcome! Say hi!", userWelcomeMessage: "welcome new user! Say hi"});

bot.add('/', new builder.CommandDialog()

    .matches("^set name", builder.DialogAction.beginDialog("/setname"))
    .matches("^quit", builder.DialogAction.endDialog())
    .onDefault(function (session) {

        if (!session.userData.name) {

            session.beginDialog("/profile");
        } else {

            session.send("Hello %s!", session.userData.name);
        }
    }
));

bot.add("/profile", [

    function (session) {

        builder.Prompts.text(session, "Hi! What is your name?");
    },

    function (session, results) {

        session.userData.name = results.response;
        session.beginDialog("/");
    }
]);

bot.add("/setname", [

    function (session) {

        builder.Prompts.text(session, "What would you like your name changed to?");
    },

    function (session, results) {

        session.userData.name = results.response;
        session.send("your name has been changed to %s", session.userData.name);
        session.endDialog()
    }
]);


//setup the restify server
var server = restify.createServer();
server.post('api/messages', bot.verifyBotFramework(), bot.listen());
server.listen(process.env.port || 3978, function () {

    console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url);
})
```

As you can see when I created the bot I set both the groupWelcomeMessage and the userWelcomeMessage parameters. Unfortunately, none of those messages show up. Thanks for the help.